# how to compare two dataframes and create a new datadrame

Tags: python, dataframe

**I have two data frames.**

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D'], 'ID2':['E','F','G','H'], 'No1':[1, 2, 3, 4]})`

**and**

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X':['X1','X2','X3','X4'], 'Y':['Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4'], 'No2':[ 3, 4, 5, 6]})`

I want to first check where the values in column `No1` in `df1` is the same as in `No2` in `df2`. for example, in this case, value 3 is the same in the third column.

Now, I want to create a **new data frame** in a way that wherever the values in `No1` and `No2` were the same, the two data frames merge in those rows.

```
df_new = [['C', 'G', 3, 'X1', 'Y1']
          ['D', 'H', 4, 'X2', 'Y2']]
```

Comment: Does the new df should be `[['C', 'G', 3, 'X1', 'Y1'],['D', 'H', 4, 'X2', 'Y2']]`?

Comment: have you tried [dataframe merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try`merge`

```py
df1.merge(df2, left_on='No1', right_on='No2', how='inner').drop(['No2'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may try the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','B','C','D'], 'ID2':['E','F','G','H'], 'No1':[1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X':['X1','X2','X3','X4'], 'Y':['Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4'], 'No2':[3, 4, 5,6]})

VarA = "No1"
VarB = "No2"
LengthofVar = len(df1[VarA])
lstofidx = []


for x in df1[VarA]:
    for y in df2[VarB]:
        if x==y:
            lstofidx.append(x-1)

newdict = {}
df2.drop(columns=VarB, inplace=True)
for x in range(len(lstofidx)):
    newidx = lstofidx[x]
    newlst = []
    for y in df1.iloc[newidx,:]:
        newlst.append(y)
    for z in df2.iloc[newidx,:]:
        newlst.append(z)
    newdictname = "Col" + str(x+1)
    newdict[newdictname] = newlst

newdf = pd.DataFrame(newdict)
print(newdf)
```

Please do take note that index wise i followed your instruction. You may append that part as you see fit.